# Model value is getting null when form post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I populate my model and pass that model to view from action method. with for loop in view I generate radio button based on model.

just see this code. here I populate my model manually and pass to view from action method.

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            var student = new StudentModel
            {
                FirstName = "Rion",
                LastName = "Gomes",

                //I think the best way to populate this list is to call a service here.
                Sex = new List<Sex>
                {
                    new Sex{ID="1" , Type = "Male"},
                    new Sex{ID="2" , Type = "Female"}
                }
            };

            return View(student);
        }
```

based on Sex property I generate no of radio button in loop and when I select any radio button and click on form submit then form data properly deserialize to my model in action method but when I am checking the sex property then I saw it is showing null value. I am new in mvc and not being able to understand why my sex property is getting null when form submit to action.

here is my full code and please tell me where I am making mistake. thanks

### controller code

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            var student = new StudentModel
            {
                FirstName = "Rion",
                LastName = "Gomes",

                //I think the best way to populate this list is to call a service here.
                Sex = new List<Sex>
                {
                    new Sex{ID="1" , Type = "Male"},
                    new Sex{ID="2" , Type = "Female"}
                }
            };

            return View(student);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(StudentModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //TODO: Save your model and redirect
            }

            //Call the same service to initialize your model again (cause we didn't post the list of sexs)
            return View(model);
        }
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

### model code

```
public class StudentModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name Required")] // textboxes will show
        [Display(Name = "First Name :")]
        [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "First Name cannot be longer than 5 characters.")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name Required")] // textboxes will show
        [Display(Name = "Last Name :")]
        [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Last Name cannot be longer than 5 characters.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }


        public List<Sex> Sex { get; set; }
      }

    public class Sex
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

### here is my view code.

```
@model MvcRadioButton.Models.StudentModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    foreach (var Sex in Model.Sex)
    {
            <div>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Sex, Sex.ID, new { @id = ("sex" + Sex.ID) })
                @*@Html.Label("Sex", sex.Type)*@
                @Html.Label("sex" + Sex.ID, Sex.Type)
            </div>
    }
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

also guide me how could I set validation on my sex property. if anyone try to submit form without selecting any radio button then a message will display. thanks please guide that where I am making mistake.

Comment: http://www.techiesweb.net/radio-button-list-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are only posting student model make a view model

like here

```
public class StudentDetailViewModel
    {
        public Student Student { get; set; }
        public Sex Sex { get; set; }
    }
```

and use this model in your index method to pass values to view also change name of model in view like following

```
StudentDetailViewModel studentvm = new StudentDetailViewModel();
studentvm.Student.firstname = -----------;
studentvm.Sex.Type = ----------;
return View(studentvm);
@model MvcRadioButton.Models.StudentDetailViewModel
```

on submit also post viewmodel to your post method

Comment: can u plzz rectify my full code so i can understand because i am new in MVC.

Comment: if i build view model then i guess we do need to have Sex reference in StudentModel class....am i right ?

Comment: i have done changes for you just change then ask if your problem was not solved and submit the error what you get and if u got the ans then please tick my answer